# TensorArray Initialization from another tensor

Tags: tensorflow

What is the right way to initialize a tensorarray from another tensor in tensorflow.

Suppose I have a tensor

```
T1 

TensorArr = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, 1, dynamic_size=True)
```

What is way to say that this tensorarray depends on T1?  Looking at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) I cant figure out how to initialize this.

Correct me if my understanding is wrong, T1 is a nested tensor and I want to loop over a dimension using tf.while_loop and hence I want to initialize the TensorArray with it.

Answer (score 1):

In documentation for [raw_rnn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py), they use

```
inputs_ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=max_time)
inputs_ta = inputs_ta.unstack(inputs)
```

*inputs* is a tensor with shape: (max_time,batch_size,num_hidden).
Hope this helps.